# Discrete maths on cardinality

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How would one proceed in solving this problem: 
if for example we have a given set A  which represents all sets of increasing functions  whose   domain and codomain are sets of integers of cardinality 7, how would one show that 
|A| = |powerset(emptyset)|  = 1;

i thought a proof by contradiction would be necessary, by assuming that there exists  2 strictly increasing  fuctions, then perhaps finally arriving to the conclusion that there is only one, but i cannot formulate a good proof.

Please i need  help

thanks

Comment: |powerset(emptyset)| = 1.

Comment: There *are* two distinct such functions, because their domains and codomains could be any two sets of $7$ numbers. So there's an infinite number of such functions.

Comment: @JackM But if you interpret the question that way, then $A$ isn't a set.

Comment: As @azimut said, $|\wp(\varnothing)|=1$, so you’re being asked to show that some set has exactly one element. It isn’t clear, however, what you mean by *a given set A which represents all sets of increasing functions whose cardinality is 7 in both domain and codomain*. What do you mean by *increasing function* in this context? In what way does $A$ *represent* sets of these functions?

Comment: i slightly modified the question. I don't know if it changes, but what i mean by an increasing function, if x2 > x1 then f(x2)>f(x1). i need prove that there is only one function that exists which possesses with property. there is no other way of creating 2 strictly increasing function in this interval

Comment: @ Brian M.Scott

Answer (score 1):

I don't think contradiction is necessary for this. I am going to assume for simplicity that the domain and codomain are both $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. It's pretty clear that any other seven-element totally-ordered sets are basically the same as this one.

Now, prove $f(n) \ge n$, perhaps by induction. A very similar argument (perhaps you might think of it as a "reverse induction", or you might want to think about $g(n) = 6 - f(6 - n)$) also shows $f(n) \le n$. But that already tells you what $f$ is!